# Are methods called in a lambda query being executed on the .Net core side and not SQL side

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have this lambda query.

```
var d = await dbset
    .Select(a => new ItemDto
    {
        Id = a.Id,
        Active = a.isActive()
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

`isActive` is defined on the dbset entity as (`State`, `StartDate`, and `StopDate` are all properties on the entity):

```
public bool isActive()
{
    return isActive(State, StartDate, StopDate);
}

public static bool isActive(State state, DateTimeOffset? startDate, DateTimeOffset? stopDate)
{
   return
     state == State.Active
     && stopDate >= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
     && startDate <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
}
```

In old Entity framework this would have failed with a smoke cloud and a nasty error that would have taken ages to track down.. in new EF Core 3.1 this runs just fine, and I can debug the `isActive` methods and step through them when they are called from the async query.

This tells me that these are run on the C#/.Net side of things, and not translated to SQL (which the old Entity framework would have tried to do).

Can someone confirm that this is actually the case, or am I missing something? If this is indeed doing what I think it is, its awesome.. and remove a bit of the headache of using these queries where before you had to worry about where the code was executed.

Comment: [Client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) is still a thing you need to be careful about. In your case, this might work because EF Core just gets the full item, projecting it on the client instead of the server. You should take a look at the generated SQL queries to verify that though. – In general, using something other than expressions will usually result in client evaluation.

Comment: Indeed, as you said, this cannot be implemented in the old entity framework, but it can be achieved in ef core, but you need to note that it is possible in ef core because the isActive method is defined in the entity. Rather than an independent method, if you call the isActive method independently(just not in entity), it will cause error too.Then,the method to solve the problem is as mentioned in [above comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this and thinks "great, this solves all my problems".
It does not.

I've been sitting with SSMS and debugging the queries for the past hour or so to figure out what is actually being sent to the SQL. And much like @poke was saying in the comment. It handles both cases, but when it encounters a query such as the one I was writing above, it gets EVERYTHING. Not just the extra fields which are used in the method, but all fields on the entity. So while this does hide away the problem and lets you write any query you want, as soon as that query hits real data it's going to bog down.

I think I prefer the old EF way of doing this (ie not at all), although it would be nice with better error messages. Or even better an option when you setup EF Core that lets you "allow" these queries, or disable them and get an error so you cant make them by mistake.

Comment: You could try `ConfigureWarnings(w => w.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning))` which should in theory cause exceptions immediately when client evaluation happens.